# How to get Oracle C++ Call interface (OCCI) working on Visual Studio?

Tags: oracle, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, oracle-sqldeveloper, occi

I'm learning and using oracle with SQL. I've created a database with OracleSQLDeveloper and now I'm trying to have access within a project writed in C++.

I've been searching and I've found that Oracle has Oracle C++ Call Interface (OCCI) and using this I can achieve what I want.

My question is, somone know's what exactly do I need to do to get OCCI working on Visual Studio? I can't get it working at all and I've spend so much time.

Hope somone can help me, thanks!

PD: Sorry for my english :)

Comment: Start by downloading [Oracle Instant Client](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html).  This has the libraries you need to link against.  I can't help with VS itself.  The general recommendation is to use the OCI API directly instead of OCCI unless you have a special reason.  OCI has more functionality.  You may also want to look at a simpler OCI wrapper like Oracle's [ODPI-C](https://github.com/oracle/odpi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the compilation script for OCCI application on Linux machine it will be more or less same on windows.

```
g++ someSourceFiles.cpp -o out -I$INC_DIR -I$ORACLE_HOME/lib -I$ORACLE_HOME/precomp/public -I$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/public -L$ORACLE_HOME/lib -locci -lclntsh -lnnz12 -lons -lclntshcore
```

Here 
$ORACLE_HOME is a environment variable mostly set in PATH variable if you are using Windows
and bash_profile if you are using Linux.

Normally it points to the ORACLE home directory

Below two points to the paths where header files required for OCCI implementation are present.

```
-I$ORACLE_HOME/precomp/public 
-I$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/public
```

Below are dynamically linked shared libraries required to access OCCI methods

```
-locci -lclntsh -lnnz12 -lons -lclntshcore
```

Below is the path where shared libraries are present.

```
-L$ORACLE_HOME/lib
```

Now your are trying to implement these on Visual studio 
you need to configure above explained variables in your project settings 
in visual studio to compile them.

NOTE: In your case shared libraries will be of .dll form as it is windows.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could include OCI/OCCI API, but I'm still getting some link errors.

[Code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfFU3.jpg)

This is the error when I try to Create the Environment. The pointer itself doesn't give any error, its the static function. Someone know's what could I have missed?

[Linker Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3raC.jpg)

Anything helps, Thanks!